# How can I make a div fadeIn only on scrolling down?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I have created a scroll-to-top function to let visitors scroll-to-top on clicking a button. That works fine. I have also made the button to appear on scroll.

What I needed is to appear when scrolled down and disappear when scrolled to top. But currently, it first appears on page load then fadeOut and again fadeIn. How can I make that appear only when the page is scrolled down?

Here is the html:

```
<div>
   <p> The page's content</p>
   <div class="scrolltop">    
       <a href="#top" id="scrolltop">Top</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is jquery:

```
<script>
  jQuery("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
     jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
     return false;
});
</script>
    <script>
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop()> 200)
     {
        jQuery('.scrolltop').fadeIn();
     }
    else
     {
      jQuery('.scrolltop').fadeOut();
     }
 });
    </script>
```

Here is the css:

```
#scrolltop {
    background-color: orange !important;
    color:#FFF;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:9999;
}

#scrolltop:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Here is my- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjeev/u6rRX/2/) for convenience

Comment: All the content, and a fiddle? +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/u6rRX/3/)***

Pretty simple fix, just hide your scroller on load.

```
jQuery('.scrolltop').hide();
```

An alternative would be to do what `hide` does internally, and simply set this class to hide by definition ([jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u6rRX/5/))

```
.scrolltop{
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick fix. As per the performance which is better? Hiding with jQuery `jQuery('.scrolltop').hide();`? or css `display:none;` ?

Comment: @IamSJ - The css approach would be preferred because it does not have to wait for `document.ready` to fire, it will just render like that. Internally, all `hide` does is change the style to `display:none` and also add some data to the jQuery object for `showing`.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your css

```
.scrolltop {
    display:none;
}
```

So its initially hidden and doesn´t have to wait for your code, far better than doing that with js

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('.scrolltop').hide() } );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6rRX/4/)